# WP_Query filter by value of Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to filter results by a custom post type

This is my while loop which returns all items. I need to filter by a date, only showing date earlier than CURDATE()

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$auction_query = new WP_Query();
$auction_query->query('post_type=auctions&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=auction_details&paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page=20');
```

in my wp_postmeta table I have the following data

```
meta_id: [id of meta row]
post_id: [id of post]
meta_key: auction_details
meta_value: a:6:{s:12:"auction_date";s:10:"2013-07-27";s:12:"auction_time";s:21:"9am Personal Property";s:16:"auction_location";s:44:"New Providence,";s:0:""
```

I need to filter by the auction date value in the meta value column when paired with the meta_key auction_details showing only posts with auction_date earlier than today's date.

Comment: This part: `meta_key=post_type=auctions` looks strange.

Comment: I think it would be eaiser if `auction_date` was a special meta key instead.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to use CURDATE because the MySQL field type used to store post_meta values is a string, and not a date.

Consider storing your time and date values

- in a separate post meta field, and
- as a unix timestamp (number value).

Then it will be easy to restrict your query with a > or < comparison, something like

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'auction_time',
            'value' => date_i18n( 'U' ),
            'compare' => '<',
        )
    )
);
$auction_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you'd like to order by this field, be sure to order by 'meta_value_num' instead of the usual 'meta_value', as the latter will order your posts lexically and not numerically.

(A word of caution: Be careful to use `date_i18n()` (a function provided by WordPress using your WordPress timezone preference) rather than `date()` (a native PHP function using your system wide timezone setting in PHP) when converting timestamps while using WordPress.)